# Selenium WebDriver wire protocol: example where “equals” returns true for different element IDs?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm studying the Selenium WebDriver wire protocol. I'm looking for an example situation in which the [“equals” command](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#/session/%3asessionId/element/%3aid/equals/%3aother) returns true for two different element IDs. In the (brief) testing I did so far, getting the same element by two different means (by tag name and by class name for example) returned the same element ID. I assume this isn't always guaranteed to be the case (otherwise I don't see the need for the “equals” command as you could simply compare the element IDs directly), but it's not clear from the documentation in which situation the element IDs might be different.

Comment: I may be mistaken but I think it was not too long ago that changes were made so elements return consistent IDs. The equals command may just be leftover from before those changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @prestomanifesto's hint, I found the related [Selenium issue #2920](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2920).

From what I understand from the discussion there, the FirefoxDriver has been fixed to return consistent IDs and it was the only one that didn't do so.

So with any of the currently implemented drivers, it's not possible to produce a situation in which the “equals” command returns true for two different element IDs. This may still be possible with some future driver though.